# With AWS Elastic Beanstalk how do the graphs work with multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When you have a load balanced elastic beanstalk instance and go from a single instance to multiple instances do the graphs such as CPUUtilization shows  the results of the two instances merged, (i.e the sum(average % cpu per instance)/2) or the total cpu utilization (i.e range now goes fro 1 to 200 %). And is there a way to view a graph of one instance within the load-balanced server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphs which are displayed within Elastic Beanstalk are combined from the data from all the EC2 instances. So the CPU graph, that is the CPU data from all the instances.

It's the same graphs as the graphs from the auto-scaling groups within CloudWatch.

If you want to see data from a single EC2 instance, go to CloudWatch and find the metrics for your particular EC2 instance.

Comment: oh great didnt know about Cloudwatch